# TAB в модальном окне, как можно исправить эту ошибку, посмотри пожалуйста на картинку

Tags: html, css, tab, modal

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
/*css*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

::selection {
    background-color: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabbed {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.tabbed > input {
    display: none;
}

.tabbed > label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color .3s;
}

.tabbed > label:hover,
.tabbed > input:checked + label {
    background: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabs {
    clear: both;
    perspective: 600px;
}

.tabs > div {
    width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
    padding: 10px 30px 40px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateX(-20deg);
    transform-origin: top center;
    transition: opacity .3s, transform 1s;

}

#tab-nav-1:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-2:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-3:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-4:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4) {
    transform: rotateX(0);
    opacity: 1;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .tabbed {
        width: 400px;
    }

    .tabbed > label {
        display: none;
    }

    .tabs > div {
        width: 400px;
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        position: relative;
        transform: none;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .tabs > div h2 {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
    }
}
   */
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить к `.tabs { position: relative; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказал @Spartacus, укажите для `.tabs {position: relative;}`.

Это обосновывается тем, что элемент с `position: absolute;`, как бы использует позиционирование относительно родителя с `position: relative;`, т.к. в вашем коде `.tabs > div {position: absolute;}` при котором `position: relative;` имеет только `body`, то и `.tabs > div` становится относительно `body`.

---

> **position: absolute** 
>  Указывает, что элемент абсолютно позиционирован, при этом другие элементы отображаются на веб-странице словно абсолютно позиционированного элемента и нет. Положение элемента задается свойствами left, top, right и bottom, также на положение влияет значение свойства position родительского элемента. Так, если у родителя значение position установлено как static или родителя нет, то отсчет координат ведется от края окна браузера. Если у родителя значение position задано как fixed, relative или absolute, то отсчет координат ведется от края родительского элемента.

[position | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)